# Symfony 2 form type add custom select

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony, select

I have a Symfony 2.3.4 form type that works, and one of the HTML tags that the form has is a select:

```
            ->add('aIdWorkerStatus', 'entity', array('class'   => 'OsdRetireBundle:WorkerStatus'
                , 'property' => 'description'))
```

The Entity WorkerStatus, has a few values and IDs and it works perfectly like that. But I have been struggling to add an arbitrary value in the select that displays a 'All' option on the select drop down list. Can any one help me?
Regards and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[empty_value](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#empty-value) is what you are looking for :

```
->add('aIdWorkerStatus', 'entity', array('class'   => 'OsdRetireBundle:WorkerStatus'
                , 'property' => 'description', 'empty_value' => 'All'))
```

Comment: This is the answer I just had to add `'required' => false` and it is working already. Thank you.